# Does the encryption in Kinesis Streams cause the outgoing records to be encrypted?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kms

I am working with a Cloudformation stack and I have a pipeline `Kinesis Stream ==> Kinesis Firehose ==> S3 Bucket`. In the [Kinesis Stream template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html#aws-resource-kinesis-stream-examples), it lists a `StreamEncryption` field and says,

> StreamEncryption
>
> Enables or updates **server-side encryption** using an
>   AWS KMS key for a specified stream.

where I bolded the statement in question.

Also, from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/encryption.html),

> When you send data from your data producers to your Kinesis stream,
>   the Kinesis Data Streams service encrypts your data using an AWS KMS
>   key before storing it at rest. When your Kinesis Data Firehose
>   delivery stream reads the data from your Kinesis stream, the **Kinesis
>   Data Streams service first decrypts the data and then sends it to
>   Kinesis Data Firehose**. Kinesis Data Firehose buffers the data in
>   memory based on the buffering hints that you specify and then delivers
>   it to your destinations without storing the unencrypted data at rest.

I want the records that ultimately end up in S3 to be encrypted using my KMS key such that a person with full access to my S3, but not KMS, would not be able to read the data.

Will this do that? If not, how do I get the data to reside "doubly" encrypted inside S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hack, that is not a good solution, but works for now is to have [Firehose do a Lambda Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) on the data, but encrypt and write the data out yourself from the Lambda.

Non ideal, but functional.